Proof verification: If $f$ is continuous and $|f(x)| \leq 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^n\ dx = 0$.
So I wanted to prove the following lemma:
Lemma. Suppose $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and satisfy $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, where equality occur at only finitely many points. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{n} dx = 0$.
I think the proof I have come up with is correct. However, I would gladly appreciate your opinion on it, if there are any mistakes I have made or if there is space for any improvements etc. Thank you in advance!
Proof. Let $a_{1}<a_{2}< \cdots < a_{m}$ be the points with $|f(x)|=1$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ be given and wlog. assume $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small. For brevity, set $a=a_{0}$ and $b=a_{m+1}$. For every $i=0,1, \ldots , m$, construct the partition $P_{i}=\{a_{i},a_{i}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)}, a_{i+1}-\frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)},a_{i+1}\}$ of the interval $[a_{i},a_{i+1}]$. Finally, set $P=P_{0} \cup P_{1} \cup \cdots \cup P_{m}$. Since $|f|$ is continuous on $[a_{i}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)}, a_{i+1}-\frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)}]$, by the Extreme Value Theorem it follows that $|f|$ has a maximum value $K_{i}$. Define $K=\max\{K_{i}:0 \leq i \leq m\}$. It follows $K \in [0,1)$. On the other hand, again by the Extreme Value Theorem, the maximum value of $|f|$ over $[a_{i},a_{i}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)}]$ and $[a_{i+1}-\frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)},a_{i+1}]$ is $\leq 1$. From here, we have
$$U(|f|^{n},P) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{m} \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)} \cdot 1 + \left(a_{i+1}-a_{i} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2(m+1)}\right)\cdot K^{n} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4(m+1)} \cdot 1\right) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + K^{n}(b-a).$$
Thus,
$$\left| \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{n} dx \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|^{n} dx \leq U(|f|^{n},P) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + K^{n}(b-a).$$
Finally, by the Archimedean principle, there exists a positive integer $N$ with $K^{N}(b-a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Hence, if $n \geq N$ then
$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{n} dx \right| < \varepsilon,$$
and by the Weierstrass definition of a limit, it immediately follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{n} dx = 0$. We are done. $\blacksquare$

Looks pretty good! One point: in the sentence "On the other hand, ..." I don't think the extreme value theorem is needed—it's clear from the hypotheses that the maximum of $|f|$ on each such interval is exactly $1$. In general, the idea to focus on small neighborhoods around the $a_i$ and then get an exponential bound on the rest of the values is, I think, the best way to approach this!
